# How do I POST a data object that contains an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, post, serialization

I want to `POST` a data object that contains an array.

I believe the object needs to be serialized before it is posted but I don't know how to do that.

I tried the below but the `serialize` function I'm using breaks because my object contains an array :

```
var serialize = function (obj, prefix) 
{
  var str = [];
  for(var p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      var k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p, v = obj[p];
      str.push(typeof v == "object" ?
        serialize(v, k) :
        encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
    }
  }
  return str.join("&");
};

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/xxxx',
  data: serialize({
    a: 'xxx',
    b: 123456,
    c: [{d: "xxx", e: "xxx"}, {d: "xxx", e: "xxx"}]
  })
});
```

});

Comment: To add to the answer under, jQuery already have a serialize() function for Form Elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AJAX data could be PlainObject/String/Array

> #### data
>
> Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>
> Data to be sent to the
>   server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.
>   It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to
>   prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If
>   value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key
>   based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/xxxx',
  data: {
    a: 'xxx',
    b: 123456,
    c: [{
      d: "xxx",
      e: "xxx"
    }, {
      d: "xxx",
      e: "xxx"
    }]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on *how* you want to serialise it. There is no standard for expressing an array in any of the standard data types that a form would support.

If you just pass the plain object to jQuery's `data` then it will serialise it as `www-url-form-encoded` using PHP's conventions for representing arrays (which you can then access via `$_POST` in PHP or with [this Perl module](https://metacpan.org/pod/PHP::ParseStr)).

If you pass it through `JSON.stringify()` then you'll get JSON (and should also specify `contentType: "application/json"`).